# Verbstellung bei Aufzählungen

Tags: sentence-structure

Ist der folgende Beispielsatz unelegant oder gar grammatisch falsch?

> Resigniert gestand sich Johann ein, dass er wahrscheinlich wieder nicht den Mut haben würde und sich stattdessen ein weiteres schlichtes und unauffälliges Hemd kaufen, wie er schon so viele hatte.

Da die Aufzählung in meinem Beispiel aus zwei langen Phrasen besteht, scheint es mir, dass der Leser bei üblicher Verbstellung (am Ende der Aufzählung) zu lange auf die Information warten muss, welches Verb denn nun kommt, und sich deshalb unangenehm lange stärker konzentrieren muss:

> Resigniert gestand sich Johann ein, dass er wahrscheinlich wieder nicht den Mut haben und sich stattdessen ein weiteres schlichtes und unauffälliges Hemd kaufen würde, wie er schon so viele hatte.

Ich würde das Hilfsverb *würde* deshalb gerne nach vorne stellen, empfinde die Fügung dann aber als auffällig ungewöhnlich. Ist sie stilistisch holprig oder sogar grammatisch falsch?

Comment: Es ist grammatisch falsch. Ein Infinitiv im Nebensatz muss immer vor dem konjugierten Verb stehen. Du hast einen Infinitiv ("kaufen"), auf den im Nebensatz kein konjugiertes Verb folgt.

Comment: @Roland Danke! Kannst du für diese Regel einen Beleg geben (Link, Buch, ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatisch kann man das m.E. durchaus so machen. Dann ist das fehlende "würde" an der zweiten Stelle eben eine Ellipse, also eine Weglassung, um die unnötige Wiederholung zu vermeiden.

Gerade in dem langen Satz und mit dem "wie..."-Anhängsel am Schluss wird es aber unübersichtlich und für den Leser schwierig, die Ellipse gleich zu bemerken und das fehlende zweite "würde" an der richtigen Stelle dazu zu denken. Subjektiv finde ich "würde" an der zweiten Position, also dein zweites Zitat, da immer noch leichter zu rezipieren. "Würde" ist auch kein so starkes und unerwartbares Verb, dass man es nicht so lange aufschieben könnte.

Vielleicht wäre es mit einem Doppelpunkt besser lesbar? Das ist aber natürlich eine Frage deines Stils.

> Resigniert gestand sich Johann ein: er würde wahrscheinlich wieder nicht den Mut haben und sich stattdessen ein weiteres schlichtes und unauffälliges Hemd kaufen, wie er schon so viele hatte.

Comment: Danke für die Rückmeldung zur Verständlichkeit und den Lösungsvorschlag mit dem Doppelpunkt!